# ParallelTable within ParallelTable

Tags: parallelization

Suppose a ParallelTable invocation parallelizes a module which in turn invokes ParallelTable.  Is it possible that there will be a deadlock situation wherein the second ParallelTable invocation can't proceed because the first one has been allocated all the available CPUs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The second one simply won't have any effect.

Just try, and see the warning messages.

[image]

You can read about how parallelization works here:

- [Parallel Computing Tools User Guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ParallelTools/tutorial/Overview.html)

It is not CPUs that get allocated, but kernel processes (of which you may launch as many as you want). If a parallel command (such as `ParallelTable`) is run on the main kernel, it distributes its computation to subkernels. If it is run on a subkernel, it reverts to the non-parallel equivalent (i.e. `Table`), and prints the above warning message.