# ParallelTable[ParallelTable] vs Table[ParallelTable]: inexplicable differences & nonlinear scaling in computation time

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation, parallelization

I have something that looks a lot like the following:

```
h[d1_,d2_,rn_,cn_]:=Flatten[d1[[
                                Max[1,1+rn];;Min[rows,rows+rn],
                                Max[1,1+cn];;Min[cols,cols+cn]
                              ]]].
                    Flatten[d2[[
                                Max[1,1-rn];;Min[rows,rows-rn],
                                Max[1,1-cn];;Min[cols,cols-cn]
                              ]]]/
                    ((rows-Abs[rn])(cols-Abs[cn]));
ParallelTable[
              w=0.02x;
              a=(Pi/10)y;
              f=Abs[t+w Exp[I a]s];
              g=ParallelTable[h[f,f,rn,cn],{rn,-10,10},{cn,-10,10}];
              total=Total[Total[g]];
              total,{x,0,3},{y,0,3}]
```

$h$ is simply the correlation of two matrices $d_1$ and $d_2$ of the same size, one of which is displaced by $r_n$ rows and $c_n$ columns, weighted by the overlap area (yes, I know of `ListCorrelate`; that's beside the point). $rows$ and $cols$ are the number of rows and columns in the matrices, respectively. $s$ and $t$ are matrices of size $rows\times cols$, so obviously $f$ is also a matrix of that size. $g$ is an $11\times11$ matrix. Finally, $total$ is the sum of all the elements of $g$.

The whole thing should result in an $4\times4$ matrix with all the values of $total$ for different values of $x$ and $y$ (or, equivalently, for different values of $w$ and $a$).

When I run this, I get the following message:

> ParallelTable::subpar: Parallel computations cannot be nested; proceeding with sequential evaluation.

(The message appears a few times per processor core before a "further output of ParallelTable::subpar will be suppressed" message appears.) However, the thing runs in under 4 seconds. If I change the first `ParallelTable` to `Table`, the error doesn't appear anymore but the thing takes about 10 seconds.

As far as I understand, the error comes up because I have a `ParallelTable` nested inside of another `ParallelTable` and what Mathematica does is turn one of them into `Table`. If this is the case, though, why does it take longer to run when I manually change one of them into `Table`?

**Edit:** I read [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163724/paralleltable-within-paralleltable) that the error results in the *second* `ParallelTable` being turned into `Table`. I suppose the stuff outside the second `ParallelTable` takes longer to evaluate than the stuff inside it (and thus it's better for the stuff outside to be parallelised than for the stuff inside to be parallelised); that would explain the computation-time difference. However, I still have another question:

Why does it take really long (it's been going on for half an hour; who knows how long it's got left) when I do this $11\times11$ times instead of $4\times4$ times (i.e. when I let $x$ and $y$ run up to 10)? If $4\times4=16$ takes under 4 seconds, I'd imagine $11\times11=121$ to take $4\times121/16=30$ seconds at most.

Thanks for any insight into this.

Comment: The main issue is probably not the stuff outside the inner `ParallelTable`, but rather the overhead of starting a parallel computation… Regarding your other issue: I cannot reproduce the timing behavior you describe. Can you provide example data for `gradhLr`??

Comment: @BrettChampion They are exact numbers.

Comment: @Mathe172 I'd already started parellel computation when I made these tests. As for `gradhLr`, that's a typo (`f` was initially called that); I'll edit my post to fix it.

Comment: @Rain There will still be some overhead - although a big part of that is indeed only done once for the first parallel computation

Comment: Can you provide `s` and `t`?

Comment: @BrettChampion Sorry for the long delay in replying. Been really busy. I don't know how the values of $s$ and $t$ are relevant, but I'll edit my question to include them.

Comment: Well, I'm trying, but my computer refuses to paste two 80,000-element arrays. I suppose it doesn't hurt to just make `RandomReal[]` arrays with, say, 1,000 elements each..